# executing sql does not work

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to execute a query in java
but it throws an exception

```
try {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DatabaseURL + DatabaseName, UserName, Password);
    System.out.println("1");
    Message = "data retrieved successfully  ...";
    //Statement st = this.conn.createStatement();// Membuat Statement
    System.out.println("2");
    pr = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT `الكلمة` FROM `name1` WHERE `الموضوع` LIKE    'أداة الطحن' ;");
    System.out.println("3");
    res = pr.executeQuery();
    System.out.println("4");
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("5");
    Message = "connection failed  \r\n " + e.getMessage();
    return null;
}
```

it prints 1 2 3  5 
so there is a problem in executing the query so that it does not print 4
I tried to run it on sql and it works
what's the problem here???

Comment: What is the error code and dbms?

Comment: Which Exception is thrown?

Comment: Do you really have a column called `الموضوع`?

Comment: can you replace `System.out.println("5");` by `e.printStackTrace();` and post the stacktrace please?

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column '??????' in 'field list'
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

Comment: it seems that dialing with arabic is the problem????

Comment: I'v changed the query so that
it becomes " SELECT * FROM `name1` "
and it works ,,, but now how can i deal with arabic in the other queries??

Comment: Did you compile your Java sources with the correct encoding? If you don't specify the encoding for the compiler the non-ASCII name probably winds up garbled in the .class file

Comment: how can i specify the encoding for the  compiler??

Comment: I found that the encoding was utf-8 and this is for arabic, but still doesn't working with arabic

Answer (score 4):

You have a semicolon at last in the query.Maybe this is the problem.